# Tough CSS issue- how to move image down or text up within a href?

Tags: html, css

I am having a frustrating CSS problem- basically I have an image that needs to be exactly inline (not above or below) text that I have all within an a href. HTML-

```
<li><a href="../php/updatestatus.php?update=true&link11=<?=$uniqid?>"><img class= "emoji" src="../images/emojis/1f642.png"/><p class="emojiText">Pretty good</p></a></li>
```

produces this:

[image]

You can see that the image is the right size but slightly too far up from the text. I have rearranged my html and stuck the text within its own `<p>`, moved the image, everything. Nothing has worked. My current CSS:

```
.emoji {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.emojiText {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
}

.status li a { 
    text-indent: 5px;
    display: block; 
    width: 250px;
color: white;
    height: 35px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;

 -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

the last block affects both but no matter how I play with the margins I can't fix the image-text align problem. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you set up a jsfiddle

Comment: have you tried vertical-align:middle;? the last block is moving both because you're applying those styles to the <a> tag that holds both the image and the text

Comment: On which selector? the .emoji?

Comment: on your text. Jonathan is right, a fiddle would help us help you

Comment: Or use Stack Snippets, the icon that looks like a page with angle brackets, which works just like jsfiddle, but is local to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the emoji and text to align their center-points...

```
.emoji,
.emojiText {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: here's a fiddle in support of your answer https://jsfiddle.net/2zu3zt9d/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you expecting...

```
<style>
a { display:inline-block; background:#52D4A4; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; padding:10px; }
a img { display:block; margin:0 auto; }
</style>

<a href="#"><img src="http://www.cmegroup.com/etc/designs/cmegroup/cmegroupClientLibs/images/iconFacebook.png">Pretty good</a>
```

Comment: No- look at my question I posted an image of what that does. Moves text down